# Pulled data using Microsoft graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-graph

I never use Microsoft graph. I just want to query to just pull a selection of users by supervisor using Microsoft graph

Comment: Do you want to use graph from PowerShell, C#, or SPFx?

Comment: SPFx, our goal is we need to pull data from delve , like department, full name, job title , Supervisor.. and filer as well .

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for the [GET /users is here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You can "play" with the Graph API using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer).

You can use the odata filter to get users whose `manager` property equal a certain value.  Or alternatively, you can get the single user object for the supervisor, then use that user object's `directReports` property to find the users that report to them.